# Display labels on minor tick in Highcharts when using tickInterval

Tags: javascript, highcharts

On a Highcharts chart with *datetime* axis, I am trying to highlight weeks. First, I had the idea to use the grid and to set *tickInterval* to `7*24*60*60*1000` and *minorTickInterval* to `24*60*60*1000`. With the option *gridLineWidth* set to `2`, the result is almost perfect.

The problem is when zooming: minor ticks appears but without label. I can not find how to add it. And the labels are not dynamic.

You can try this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/gdebrion/19x4nmp5/19/
First chart is the basic one. When you zoom you can see the changes in x-axis.
Second chart is mine. The weeks are visible but when zooming in until having a day display on the full width, and the only ticks visible are the minor one, without label…

Please tell me if you have an idea. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The API does not provide a way to display labels on minor ticks.
http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/axes

> MINOR TICKS
>
> If the minorTickInterval option is set, minor ticks are laid out between the major ones. This includes minor tick marks, and minor grid lines, which have their own options for look and feel, but **excludes labels**.

Having a peek at the source code for Highcharts, I also do not see any label representation for minor ticks as there are for the major ticks (axis.labelEdge = [];) .
https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/blob/b6bc666da00d37c5c4e3c0d7fe238b8526e583ea/js/parts/Axis.js

```
    ...
    // Major ticks
    axis.ticks = {};
    axis.labelEdge = [];
    // Minor ticks
    axis.minorTicks = {};

    // List of plotLines/Bands
    ...
```

UPDATE:
Here is a slightly rough solution to enable minor tick labels for highcharts:
http://jsfiddle.net/strince/deuez7gk/

The code doesn't handle overlapping labels when the zoom is far out so you'll need to zoom in a bit to see it work.

The chart code was updated with:

```
  // Keep track of elements created. 
  var minorTickLabels = new Array();

  ...

  events: {
    load: function() { addMinorTickLabels(this); },
    redraw: function() { addMinorTickLabels(this); }
  }

  ...

function addMinorTickLabels(chart) {
// The elements need to be destroyed, otherwise a dictionary
// internal to highcharts will accumulate and pollute the chart.
for (var i = 0; i < minorTickLabels.length; i++) {
    var textItem = minorTickLabels[i];
  textItem.destroy();
}
minorTickLabels = new Array();

var axis0 = chart.xAxis[0];
var lastIndexFound = 0;

for (var tick in axis0.minorTicks) {
  var el = axis0.minorTicks[tick];

  // Skip double labels on major ticks.
    var index = axis0.tickPositions.indexOf(el.pos, lastIndexFound);
    if (index >= 0) {
    listIndexFound = index;
    continue;
  }

        var xPos = el.mark.getBBox().x;
  var yPos = el.mark.getBBox().y;
  var labelText = 0;

        // The formatting parameters below should be passed in.
        var textItem = chart.renderer.text(Highcharts.dateFormat("%d. %b", el.pos), xPos, yPos)   
  .css({
    color: '#101010',
    fontSize: '8px'
  })
  .attr({
    rotation: -25,
    zIndex: 6
  });

  // Add the tick label to the chart.
  textItem.add();

  minorTickLabels.push(textItem);
}
```

};